# AWT: calculate component dimensions immediately

Tags: java, awt, thinlet

I am currently fixing a bug in a (rather old) application:

It involves a tree which has a lazy load function and which has a quick search text field. Assume the following scenario:

1. Someone types a string in the quick search text field
2. This causes a query is sent to a server in background, searching available tree nodes with the entered name and offers them in a drop down style.
3. The user selects an item from the drop down list.
4. All nodes in the tree that are in the path to the selected element are expanded, causing the lazy load tree to load... well... a bunch of nodes.
5. The tree (which has a scroll bar) scrolls, so that the selected element will be in view.

Steps 1 through 4 work just fine, but step five only works if the tree does not need to lazy load elements, but has already loaded the tree sometime before.

After a while of debugging I figured that this is because the code which figures out how much to scroll uses the dimensions of the AWT elements that represent tree nodes. But if the elements were lazy loaded, the dimensions were not calculated, yet and thus the code is ineffective. I guess dimension calculation will happen during the repaint method. Or at any rate: too late.

How can I get AWT to calculate component sizes immediately?

The code uses [Thinlet](http://thinlet.sourceforge.net) on top of AWT.

Comment: Do you know at least how much visible tree elements are above to node you want to select, and deeply it is in the tree?  Is it possible to know this before lazy loading happened?  If no, then AWT cannot do magic.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov: No, I don't know this before lazy loading, but the lazy load code is synchronous. The elements will be completely loaded before I execute the scroll code. All data is there, it is just not rendered, yet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is more on the side of Thinlet and not on the side of AWT. And it looks like it is a bug in Thinlet. Thinlet does try do layout the node you want to scroll to before doing actual scrolling, but this is not correctly implemented for nodes.

Use the following patch to get thinlet to properly work in your case:

```
--- Thinlet.java        2005-03-28 18:15:28.000000000 +0200
+++ Thinlet_new.java    2013-02-06 16:06:23.707530066 +0100
@@ -166,6 +166,10 @@

        private void doLayout(Object component) {
                String classname = getClass(component);
+               while ("node" == classname) {
+                 component = getParent(component);
+                 classname = getClass(component);
+               }
                if ("combobox" == classname) {
                        if (getBoolean(component, "editable", true)) {
                                Image icon = getIcon(component, "icon", null);
```